# Python , Convert A Representation of A Binary to A Real Binary Value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing a homework project about cryptography in Python. I need to convert a string representation of binary to a real binary. I mean;
`binary = "00000011"` should be converted to real 8bits , since I will use it for a XOR operation. How can I convert it in this way in Python?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `int()` function to make it an integer, which takes a radix parameter:

```
>>> int("00000011", 2)
3
```

Once you have an integer, you can use the `^` xor operator:

```
>>> 3 ^ 1
2
```